# Existence of Frechet Derivative of Log-Normalizer for Exponential Family Type Distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let's say we have a density function that generalizes the exponential family slightly
\begin{align}
p(t)=q(t)\exp(f(t)-A(f))
\end{align}
where if $f(t)=\theta^T \phi(t)$ we recover the exponential family. Assume that $f\in L^\infty$, so that $A:L^\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We want to check if $A(f)=\log\int q(t)\exp(f(t))dt$ is Frechet differentiable. We can start by computing the Gateaux differential
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr\vert_{\epsilon=0} A(f+\epsilon g)&=\frac{\int q(t)\exp(f(t)+\epsilon g(t))g(t)dt}{\int q(t)\exp(f(t))dt}\biggr\vert_{\epsilon=0}\\
&=\mathbb{E} g(T)
\end{align}
Now we would like to show
\begin{align}
A(f+g)=A(f)+\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr\vert_{\epsilon=0} A(f+\epsilon g)+o(\Vert g\Vert)
\end{align}
in order to show existence of the Frechet derivative (if it does in fact exist). We start with
\begin{align}
A(f+g)-A(f)&=\log \frac{\int q(t)\exp(f(t)+g(t))dt}{\int q(t)\exp(f(t))dt}\\
&=\log \mathbb{E} \exp (g(T))
\end{align}
We then want to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{g\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log \mathbb{E}\exp(g(T))-\mathbb{E}g(T)}{\Vert g\Vert_\infty}=0
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to show that either this holds or doesn't hold.

Comment: To talk about Fréchet differentiability you need to have some Banach space in mind (hence a norm). I would compute the derivative of the map $f \mapsto \int q (t) e^{f(t)} dt $ first and then use the composition rule. Unless there is something weird going on, the derivative map would be $h \mapsto \int q (t) e^{f(t)} h(t) dt $. (This comes from the approximation $e^{h(t)} \approx 1 + h(t)$.)

Comment: Thanks, I set it to $L^\infty$ as the Banach space. I will try to work through this sketch.

Comment: You would need some conditions on $f,q$ to finish.

Comment: Doesn't the derivative map have the normalization constant on the bottom also or no? Also, what kinds of conditions?

Comment: I was just computing the derivative of $\phi(f)= \int q (t) e^{f(t)} dt$ which is a linear map $D \phi(f)h = \int q (t) e^{f(t)} h(t) dt$, just as the derivative of $g(x) = e^x$ would be $Dg(x)h = e^x h$. There is no normalisation.